# Start call to application endpoint (Graph / Teams bot)

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a teams calling enabled channel registration that works fine. We can use it to call PSTN and teams users (by their azure object id). However, we seem unable to call / invite an application endpoint.

I suspect this is because I dont know the correct way of identifying this application endpoint. E.g., for pstn, we use:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/call
 //...call JSON, only relevant part
 "targets":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
         "identity":{
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
            "phone":{
               "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identity",
               "id":"<phonenumber>"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
```

For user, it is with "user" property and the azure object id, which also works.

So we tried a couple of things for application / applicationInstance / object id / sip uri/ etc. using another endpoint in the same tenant as the teams users, but it persistently comes back with "Request authorization tenant mismatch." - which seems a rather generic message, because if you dont specify any id, youll get the same.

1. Can you start a call using sip adress?
2. Can you start a call to another application endpoint / resource account?

Comment: SIP device users can make calls to the Public Switched Telephone Network (PSTN), to other SIP devices, and to Teams and Skype for Business users. SIP device users can only call users who have phone numbers.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/sip-gateway-plan#benefits-of-sip-gateway:~:text=SIP%20device%20users%20can%20make%20calls%20to%20the%20Public%20Switched%20Telephone%20Network%20(PSTN)%2C%20to%20other%20SIP%20devices%2C%20and%20to%20Teams%20and%20Skype%20for%20Business%20users.%20SIP%20device%20users%20can%20only%20call%20users%20who%20have%20phone%20numbers.

Comment: Is this completely true in all scenarios? I mean, we also have teams user without a phone number and i am perfectly fine calling that by it's azure id... Thus, i understand this is the case for 'tenant-to-tenant' calls (as there must be a path from a to b), but for users / applications within your own tenant I think it is not always the case.

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team. We will let you know once we get any updates from them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to start a call using sip adress and start a call to another application endpoint / resource account.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)